# Why would links break bc of JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

[On this site](https://www.workwave.com/events), which is on Joomla and using a plugin called Matukio, the links on the left used to work, but no longer do and we are desperate to figure out why.

The company who makes the plugin replied with this info, but it sounds like he's just spouting a bunch of stuff that isn't really the cause (JUri::root() is working fine, the VWO stuff was there before when the links worked, etc).

I doubt anyone can give much insight based on this limited info, but just taking a shot bc stackoverflow is literally the best site on the internet for help. If anyone has any ideas on things i should look at, test, please share...

FROM MATUKIO:

> you have JavaScript errors on your page (not caused by Matukio):
>
> ```
> 07:43:49.475 ReferenceError: Heatmap is not defined
> <anonym>events:129
> 1events:129:3
>
> ga('set', 'VWO', Heatmap);
> ```
>
> Additionally the following is failing:
>
> ```
> 07:44:55.490 Loading of mixed contents "http://www.workwave.com/index.php?option=com_matukio&view=requests&format=raw&task=route_link&link=index.php%3FItemid%3D283%26option%3Dcom_matukio%26view%3Deventlist%26art%3D0%26catids%3D0%26search%3D%26limit%3D10%26dateid%3D2%26fees%3D0%26locations%3D0%26organizers%3D0%26ordering%3D1%26start%3D0&Itemid=283" was blocked .1jquery.min.js:5:25679
> ```
>
> As you see the link looks right, but hte protocol is wrong. E.g. http
>   instead of https.. Are you using any plugin for https redirection? Or
>   htaccess? It seems that JUri::root() is not working correct on your
>   instance. Joomla has a setting for https in the global config.

Kind regards,
Yves

Comment: I can see they asked you a couple of questions about HTTPS. Can we see your answer?

Comment: We do not use the core Joomla HTTPS method. Instead we add a few lines of PHP script to the index.php file for the template.   But we've been doing that from the time the site went live, and these links worked before when that was in place like it is now. So strange

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without more information but it looks like your site is using HTTPS. This is a good thing. But one of the restrictions is that if you're using a secure connection, then you can't access resources that are stored on a server using the non-secure HTTP protocol (it's kind of buying a fancy lock for your front door and then leaving the window open.)

This is *likely* coming from the Heatmap library. If you're pull this library from a CDN, try changing the url to "https://" instead of "http://" and this *should* fix it.